# CodeIgniter Active Record equal to for date

Tags: php, postgresql, activerecord, codeigniter-3

In CodeIgniter using active record, how do I perform a date equal to in:

```
$this->db->where()
```

date format: `$today_date=date('m/d/Y');`

```
public static function getShop($today_date) {
    $CI = & get_instance();
    $CI->db->select('url');
    $CI->db->where('AddDate', $today_date);
    $CI->db->from('tblShop');
    $query = $CI->db->get();
    return($query->result_array());
}
```

Maybe someone could help me on this.

Comment: you are passing the today date right then what is th eproblem???

Comment: return null array, while using this query,

Comment: print_r($this->db->last_query()); keep this and print the query and then execute it in database see what is happening...

Comment: see one more datbase always store the date in the format of year-month-date but you are passing the date differently that is what the reason for that the records are not fetching...

Comment: pass the data like this $today_date=date('y-m-d'); then you will get result..

Comment: while using the above format got ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "17-02-17" LINE 3: WHERE "AddDate" = E'17-02-17' ^ HINT: Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting...In my postgresDB date format : "AddDate" DATE (value inserted as : 2/17/2017)

Comment: keep capital Y instead of small y database format should be (2016-02-17) like this)

Comment: which is the datatype you are using in database for AddDate??

Comment: Field type is DATE, using postgreSQl

Comment: ok you are having recoreds in the database with that date??

Comment: yes already 7 records in th table

Comment: you are missing somewhere yaar

Comment: public static function getShop($today_date) {
    $todaydate='2017-02-17';
    $CI = & get_instance();
    $CI->db->select('url');
    $CI->db->where('AddDate', $todaydate);
    $CI->db->from('tblShop');
    $query = $CI->db->get();
    return($query->result_array());
} try this..

Comment: sorry, its not working

Answer (score 1):

Please use correct date format to compare to database field,
also use MySQL date function to exclude time while comparing.

```
$today_date=date('Y-m-d');

public static function getShop($today_date) {
    $CI = & get_instance();
    $CI->db->select('url');
    $CI->db->where('DATE(AddDate)', $today_date);
    $CI->db->from('tblShop');
    $query = $CI->db->get();
    return($query->result_array());
}
```